# Is $1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}-\cdots=\ln 2$ true?

Tags: sequences-and-series, logarithms, power-series, taylor-expansion

This might be an extremely stupid question but I stuck on two different definition of series expansion of $\ln(1+x)$. In  [this](http://www.ias.ac.in/article/fulltext/reso/012/01/0023-0037) Resonance article, the author assert that -
$$1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}-\cdots=\ln 2$$
based on the series expansion $\ln(1+x)=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^4}{4}+\frac{x^5}{5}-\cdots  $ for $-1<x\leq1$.

While the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#List_of_Maclaurin_series_of_some_common_functions) article says $\ln(1+x)=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^4}{4}+\frac{x^5}{5}-\cdots  $ for $-1<x<1$.

Now these two definition looks confusing to me, as one definition includes the $1$ while other excludes it. If the first definition is true , then the sum of the series is correct, while other definition says it's not.

Am I missing something obvious? Please can somebody explain this to me ? Thanks.

Comment: The precise statement is that the Taylor series for $\ln(1+x)$ is _absolutely_ convergent for $-1<x<1$. By contrast, it is _conditionally_ convergent to $\ln 2$ at $x=1$.

Comment: Wikipedia article clearly says that the series expansion holds for $|x|<1$, how can i just take $x=1$? @Kaynex

Comment: @Semiclassical oh I didn't know that. Can I see some proof? That would be great.

Comment: @KushalBhuyan: do you think that $1<1$ ?

Comment: With continuity.

Comment: @YvesDaoust no.

Comment: The Wikipedia link that you provided does not specify this equation.

Comment: why not @barakmanos?

Comment: Well, it's simply not there as far as I can see. If it appears further down the page (which I also haven't been able to find), then please link that section directly.

Comment: Well it is further down there, I don't know how to link that particular section but it is under the header -"List of Maclaurin series of some common functions". @barakmanos. But it is there.

Comment: @barakmanos this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#List_of_Maclaurin_series_of_some_common_functions

Comment: Alternating series with decreasing absolute values always converge, I believe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is true and the Wikipedia article should have $\le 1$ at the end.  Expansions like this have a [radius of convergence,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence) in this case $1$.  For $x$ less than the radius the series converges absolutely.  For $x$ outside the series diverges.  When $x$ is equal to the radius it takes closer analysis.  Here the series is conditionally convergent as we can show
$$\sum _{i=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{i+1}}i=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac 1{2i-1}-\frac 1{2i}\\
=\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac 1{2i(2i-1)}\\
\lt \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac1{(2i-1)^2}$$
which we know converges.

Answer (score 3):

Adding another way of proving the result. This requires less technology (without Abel's theorem). Instead I use a trick specific to this power series (well, it applies to some others as well).

Consider the series
$$
x-\frac {x^2}2+\frac{x^3}3-\frac{x^4}4+\cdots
$$
in the interval $x\in(0,1]$. It is an alternating series where the sequence formed by the absolute values of the terms, $(x^n/n)$, A) decreases, B) converges to zero. Therefore, by Leibniz criterion on alternating series:

1. The series converges to a limit $S(x)$ for all $x\in(0,1]$.
2. The cut-off error $$R_n(x)=|S(x)-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}x^k}k|<\frac{x^n}n\le\frac1n.$$

Item 2 shows that the series converges **uniformly** in the interval $x\in(0,1]$. Therefore we can conclude that $S(x)$ is continuous in that interval.

When $x\in(0,1)$ the series $S(x)$ is also obtained by integrating a uniformly converging geometric series term-wise. Therefore we know that $S(x)=\ln(1+x)$ whenever $x\in(-1,1)$.

**The finishing touch:** We know that both $S(x)$ and $\ln(1+x)$ are continuous in $(0,1]$. We also know that $S(x)=\ln(1+x)$ for all $x\in(0,1)$. By continuity
$$\ln(2)=\lim_{x\to1-}\ln(1+x)=\lim_{x\to1-}S(x)=S(1).$$

Answer (score 1):

That the series expansion of $\ln(1+x)$ holds for $x=1$ is a consequence of Abel's Limit theorem

Comment: True, but not likely to help the OP given his likely level of knowledge.

Comment: I don't know about this theorem. Can you explain a little more about it?

Comment: The lack of any explanation of Abel's limit theorem renders this answer pretty unhelpful.

Comment: @semiclassical:  everyone who is interested in this subject should be able to consult Google -> Abel's Theorem.

Comment: @Fred That would be fine for a comment, but not for an answer. In general, answers should try to minimize the number of hoops we need to jump through.