# Summation of a series $1+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{7}-\frac{1}{4}++-...$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I need to calculate the sum of the series:$T_{3n}=$ $1+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{7}-\frac{1}{4}++-...$ I know that $T_{3n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{4k-3}+\frac{1}{4k-1}-\frac{1}{2k}$. And they gave a hint that $u_n=S_n-I_n$ , where $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}$ and $I_n=\log(n)$, converges. Can anyone give me a direction? I've tried to write $T_{3n}$ in terms of $S_n$ but without success.

Comment: Ah, so the general pattern is odd, odd, even (subtracting)?

Comment: Look at $S_{4n} - T_{3n}$.

Comment: What *is* the series? Is $T_{3n} = \sum $ a definition or something deduced?  If $T_{3n} = \sum$ what the heck are $T_{3n-2}$ and $T_{3n -1}$?   What is ++- supposed to be.

Comment: Okay so if $T_n = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i$ then $a_{3n} = -\frac 1{2n}; a_{3n+1} \frac 1{4n+1}; a_{3n+1} = \frac 1{4n+3}$?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Add two hopefully known converging series term-wise:

$$
\begin{array}{cccccccccccc}
&1&-&\dfrac12&+&\dfrac13&-&\dfrac14&+&\dfrac15&-&\dfrac16&+&\dfrac17&-&\dfrac18&+&\dfrac19&-&\dfrac1{10}&+&\cdots\\
\\
&0&+&\dfrac12&+&0&-&\dfrac14&+&0&+&\dfrac16&+&0&-&\dfrac18&+&0&+&\dfrac1{10}&+&\cdots\\
\\
\hline
\\
=&1&+&0&+&\dfrac13&-&\dfrac12&+&\dfrac15&+&0&+&\dfrac17&-&\dfrac14&+&\dfrac19&+&0&+&\cdots
\end{array}
$$

Comment: Hi, did you mean something like that?: $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nx^n}{n}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{2n}$=$ln(1+x)+\frac12ln(1+x)=_{(x=1)}\frac32ln(2)$

Comment: Yup, @CodeHoarder. That was the idea. Provided that you already know that your series sums to $\ln2$, when $x=1$. That fact is often covered, but it isn't entirely trivial.

Comment: @CodeHoarder: Also take a look at [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2049317/11619).

Comment: There's a little problem. There's a theorem that basically says that you can't change the order of an infinite sum unless it absolutely converges, so i need to show that the power series i've shown here converge absolutely.

Comment: @CodeHoarder That's exactly the point here (the end result has the terms of the first series but in different order). And if you look carefully you see that I am not doing anything like changing the order of the summation. I am adding two convergent series term-by-term. And that is something we are allowed to do even to conditionally convergent series.

Comment: In other words that power series converges absolutely only when $|x|<1$. It converges only conditionally when $x=1$, which is why I am careful (and didn't ruin all math because the end result shows that the sum changes, when we reorder the terms in a way that we take two positive terms to each negative term.

Answer (score 1):

Let $H_n=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}$ 
Then as is well known $H_n-\ln n$ converges to $\gamma$

Now $$T_n=H_{4n-1}-\frac{1}{2}H_{2n-1}-\frac{1}{2}H_n$$ thus

$$T_n-\ln (4n-1)+\frac{1}{2}\ln (2n-1)+\frac{1}{2}\ln n \to 0$$ and

$$T_n\to \frac{3}{2}\ln 2$$

Comment: This answer seems to be at variance with the accepted answer. But I don't see an error in my calculations.

Comment: I just saw that answer first. And i don't quite understand this one.

Comment: Yeah I made some error also, hope its correct now, gotta have dinner now, merry Christmas.

Comment: Thanks, it's all clear now, merry Christmas